# ODBC/JDBC Driver to Azure connection fails with a 401/403 error when connecting via Power BI/ Python / Tableau

Tags: python, azure, powerbi, odbc, tableau-api

I am trying to connect to my companys databricks and I can write a sql script in the notebook and it gives me an output. However, I am currently trying to connect to databricks via python/power bi and i keep getting a 401 and/or 403 error.

[image]

^ these are the settings in azure for me.

[image]

^^ this is how i put it into the simba spark odbc driver DSN setup.
[image]

^ these are my http properties and SSL options as inputted.

[image]

^^ ODBC datasource administrator in 64 bit

[image]

[image]

this is the error that im getting.

[image]

^ this is the output when i try to make a connection through python

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue and then figured the Personal Access Token was not created. When we cloned the cluster, we missed to create a new token. Once I created the token and provided it, I was able to connect both JDBC and ODBC.

Let me know if that works.

Edit: We also realized, before this test, we didn't actually login to Microsoft Azure from this machine in a browser. During this new test with the correct token, we had logged in to the Azure portal from the same machine.

So we wanted to check  if thats a problem and signed out from the Azure portal and we were getting similiar errors again. So, if you can , login in your browser to Azure portal in the same machine where you use the ODBC DSN and see if it works.